# Match everything to the right of a particular character

Tags: regex, grep

I want to match a regex like:

```
.+|(.+)
```

but sometimes the input is like:

```
.+|.+|.+|.+|.+
```

In other words, I don't know how many pipe characters `|` are in the input string, but I know I want to extract whatever is to the right of the rightmost `|`.

Comment: Are you examples the actual regex or the sample text input?

Answer (score 4):

> In other words, I don't know how many pipe characters `|` are in the input string, but I know I want to extract whatever is to the right of the rightmost `|`

You can use the following:

```
[^|]+$
```

Regular expression:

```
[^|]+   any character except: '|' (1 or more times)
 $      before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

So for example using grep:

```
echo ".+|.+|.+|.+|foo" | grep -Eo '[^|]+$' 
# => 'foo'
```

You could also use a one-liner to do this, Example:

```
perl -nle 'print $_ for (split /\|/)[-1]' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.`, use a character class matching any character other than `|`:

```
^.+\|([^|]+)$
```

Comment: If the OP wants everything after the rightmost `|`, then why would there be `|` characters after it?

Comment: There wouldn't be any.  `[^|]` matches any character other than `|`.

Comment: Ah, because the first `.+` is a greedy match.  I see.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the end of your example is the end of the string/line, you can specify the end of line to get the value on the right of the rightmost pipe:

```
^.+\|(.+)$
```

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/wR3lP2

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `^.+\|([^|]+).*$`, which in the the case the string ends with |, will capture like so:

```
.+|.+|.+|.+|.+|
```

Captures `.+`

The other suggestions that don't negate the | captures `.+|`

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following Regex...

```
\|(\.\+)$
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

or use this simple pattern `([^|]+)$`